# overflow:auto inside a table in IE11

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-11

I'm creating an HTML table (the use of `<table>` is required) with a fixed-height `<td>` element, and am trying to add a scrollable div (overflow:auto) and a height of 100%. This works fine in Chrome. In IE11, however, the element still just expands to fit the size of it's content. This is not a problem when the scrollable div is inside of another div; only when inside a table. Here's a snippet that exemplifies the problem:

```
<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:50px; width:100px; border: 1px solid black;">
                <div style="height:100%; overflow:auto">
                    content!<br/>
                    content!<br/>
                    content!<br/>
                    content!<br/>
                    content!<br/>
                    content!<br/>
                    content!<br/>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div style="height:50px; width:100px; border: 1px solid black;">
        <div style="height:100%; overflow:auto">
            content!<br/>
            content!<br/>
            content!<br/>
            content!<br/>
            content!<br/>
            content!<br/>
            content!<br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

I would expect both content areas to be scrollable, but in IE11, only one of them is. Does anyone have any insight as to why this happens, or have a good way of being able to keep a relative height on the scrollable div? I know I can get around the problem by (a) ditching the table or (b) giving the scrollable div a fixed height, but neither of these are very attractive options to me.

Comment: Basically, you need to set the `<td>` element to `display: block;` but I am still trying to find out why in the W3 Spec. IE11 seems to be alone in not letting the div override the display property of the parent td.

Comment: @TylerH I've tried adding `display: block;` directly to the inline style of the `<td>` element, but it still doesn't seem to have any effect. In fact, I cycled through all `display` style attributes, and none of them seem to have any visual impact on the `<td>` element (aside from `display: none;`)

Comment: @packerfan3611: Setting it to display block does work for me using the code you have given, although of course doing that breaks the table structure.

Comment: @packerfan3611 Like BoltClock, it works for me in IE11 http://jsfiddle.net/tk1a47f6/

Comment: I'd like to think this is one of those long-standing IE bugs.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm using IE 11.0.9600.17498 and am unable to use a newer version for the project I'm working on. I have to wonder if there was a fix sent out for this that I don't have.

Comment: Any minor version bumps are usually security updates, not layout engine updates. I don't think it would change anything.

Comment: @BoltClock Actually, it works for me as expected in JSFiddle. But after I copied that JSFiddle HTML/CSS into a local HTML file and running it from there, the problem persisted.

EDIT: I didn't have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of my document; adding that in seems to have fixed the problem...

Comment: @BoltClock, Actually, that's no longer true.  IE11 has had at least two feature/layout changing updates since it was originally released.  For details, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn798774(v=vs.85).aspx.  It's a bit hard to read, but if you dig into the details, they're there.

Comment: @Lance Leonard: Thanks for the heads-up. It'd be interesting to know if IE11 will continue receiving feature changes once Spartan/W10 comes around.